# Inverse Gamma Distribution and Pareto distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X|\Theta$~exponential mean $\Theta$ and $\Theta$~inverse gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha,\theta$. Then $X$ follows a 2-parameter Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha,\theta$ matching the parameters of the inverse gamma mixing distribution.

I would like to know what's this statement saying and hope someone who is strong in statistic could provide the proof of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is exponentially distributed with a known mean $\Theta$, it has support $[0,\,\infty)$, and on that support its pdf is $\frac{1}{\Theta}\exp-\frac{x}{\Theta}$. But what if $\Theta$ were itself a random variable? (Well, for starters it'd make us feel better about capitalising it instead of writing $\theta$.) Then we want to average the above function of $x,\,Theta$ to get a pdf that depends only on $x$ (and parameters of the distribution of $\Theta$. In your question, $\Theta$ also has support $[0,\,\infty)$, and on that support its pdf is $\frac{\Theta^{-\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\theta^\alpha}\exp-\frac{\theta}{\Theta}$. So the pdf of $X$ becomes $$\int_0^\infty d\Theta\frac{\Theta^{-\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\theta^\alpha}\exp-\frac{\theta}{\Theta}\cdot\frac{1}{\Theta}\exp-\frac{x}{\Theta}=\alpha\theta\left(1+\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{-\alpha-1}.$$As expected, it's a Pareto distribution's pdf.